# My calculator app doesn't work with brackets?

Tags: java, android

I'm making a calculator app in Android Studio. I want to make the app work with brackets but when I included brackets in the string it didn't give any result. I used exp4j and javaluator libraries but none could resolve this issue. I don't know where I am going wrong. I'm a beginner.

```
String r = result.getText().toString();
Expression calc = new ExpressionBuilder(r).build();
                        Double res = calc.evaluate();
                        result.setText(res.toString());
```

result is textView. Here I've used exp4j library

Comment: Can you include a specific input string?

Comment: String r contains the expression!

Comment: Use logs to check the value of the output string!

Comment: Yes, but can you put in the question a string you used to test this code? What specific value did you pass to `new ExpressionBuilder(r)`.

Comment: @Daniel! Just any simple expression ! 9+(6*3)